# Base driver circuit?

Tags: bjt

I'm in need of a circuit that can be used both for driving a BJT (NPN & PNP).

The devices will only be "small" devices in TO92 packages that don't dissipate too much power so the requirements for max. voltage and current are not high.

+/-20mA max.

In order to drive the circuit I have a DAC which is capable to output voltage of +/- 10V 24bit resolution.

The source should look like a current source with high Z. Any suggestions?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? What power supplies do you have available?

Comment: Is the current your desired range of current? Or the ability of your DAC?

Comment: @ThePhoton This will be part of a test instrument. I have +/- 15V supplies available.

Comment: @jonk I was away and could not access the website... Sometimes you need to wait a bit. Currents from nA to 20mA max.

Comment: @user34920 I still don't know what your DAC is capable of sourcing or sinking. But one basic idea is presented. If you use well matched BJTs and resistors (as appropriate) there may be a few nA of offset current with 0 V applied. That could be compensated. You don't write about accuracy. That's another issue. But in any case, I've probably had my say unless you have questions about it. Others perhaps will pony up something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. No reply, so this is what you get from me:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjPeNt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That will do slightly more than \$\pm 20\:\textrm{mA}\$ from a \$\pm 10\:\textrm{V}\$ DAC control voltage (since \$R_{10}=470\:\Omega\$ instead of \$500\:\Omega\$), into a load of up to \$2.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ (\$50\:\textrm{V}\$ compliance.) It also requires \$\pm 20\:\textrm{mA}\$ from your DAC, too.

You should use beta matched BJT pairs for \$Q_3\$, \$Q_5\$, \$Q_4\$, and \$Q_6\$ -- such as the BCM61 and BCM62. (I didn't add beta-mismatch compensation to the circuit.) Cheaper (and somewhat riskier) would be the BCV61 and BCV62, as those aren't beta-matched. But all of those are at least thermally connected so their \$V_{BE}\$ should track well. The resistor values for \$R_1\$, \$R_3\$, \$R_2\$ and \$R_4\$ should be matched as precisely as you care to provide. Accuracy for them isn't as critical, as \$R_{10}\$ sets the conversion of voltage to current. Make \$R_{10}\$ as accurate as you want. The other resistors are less critical, though \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ need to be adjusted per the opamp being used.

There is no possible way this is going to give you anything like 24 bits of linearity, precision, or accuracy (no one can provide that kind of accuracy.) But you are just using this for driving a base current, I gather. It should be okay for BJT parameter extraction and curve tracing.

Comment: Can you describe your circuit bit more?

Comment: @G36 I could. Anything in particular?

Comment: +1 for cleverness, but really if OP doesn't explain themselves well enough to answer, the correct response is to vote to close, not taunt them with an answer like this.

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't see any votes to close, now or then. Would I be the only one? Anyway, sometimes the question just seems to beg for a little jerk on the chain.

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay. I see a vote. Added mine.